# Exporting particular data points of simulations from ltspice

Tags: ltspice

The simulation does repeated analysis with a parameters which grows at each new analysis. For each of those analysis which depends only on the value of the parameter which is growing, I would like to export 1 point at a certain time t0. The goal is just to see how evolve the point in function of the parameter which is growing. Does I need to export the data from LTspice ? And how can I specify when (at t0) I want to export the point ? Or is it possible to see it on LTspice ? Otherwise is it possible to export each all datas of each analysis ? I could do a post treatment of the overall datas.

Thank you very much !

Comment: You can force output at particular time increments, even though it's computing at finer steps. You can also inhibit output for some startup period, while the system comes to equilibrium for instance. Either of those should be able to give you an output at your specified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.meas` commands for that. Suppose `V(x)` is the waveform of interest, and you're interested in `time=1m`:

```
.meas tmp param V(x) at 1m
```

After the simulation is done, activate the schematic window and press `Ctrl+L` to bring up the error log. Right-click inside it and choose `Plot .step'ed .meas data`. The newly opened window will have the variation of the voltage as the parameter was changed. Here's an example:

[image: test]

If you need exporting, right-click inside the `.meas` plot window and then, from the `File > Export data as text`.

Comment: Thank a lot ! Really nice explanation :)